# How to wrap JsonObjectRequest and Volley to be simpler to use?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send request to API and get a response in JSON format in Android. I use Volley for helping me. I intend to wrap JsonObjectRequest in VolleyHelper to make it easier for me to use it. The problem is that onResponse() of JsonObjectRequest is void so that I can't return JSON object. My idea is to make my api call a simple just like this.

`JSONObject response = VolleyHelper.getInstance(this).get(url);`

`JSONObject response = VolleyHelper.getInstance(this).post(url, params);`

Below is my helper code using singleton pattern as suggest by [Google](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton).

**VolleyHelper**

```js
public class VolleyHelper {
    private static VolleyHelper mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;

    public static synchronized VolleyHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleyHelper(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private VolleyHelper(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    private <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public JSONObject get(String url) {

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                //return jsonObject;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //return jsonerror
            }
        });

        addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    public JSONObject post(String url, Map<String, String> params) {

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                //return jsonObject;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //return jsonerror
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return params;
            }
        };

        addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to return anything from an async-operation synchronously. The whole async-layer in android - be it plain `AsyncTask` or `Volley` - is built with another pattern -> the `callback`. The callback in this case is something which gets called upon completion of a "long-running" network task.

So, you should design your helper class so:

```
public interface OnFinishListener { public void onFinish( JSONObject o ); }

public class VolleyHelper {

    public JSONObject get(String url, OnFinishListener ofl ) {

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                ofl.onFinish( jsonObject );
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //return jsonerror
            }
        });

        addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
OnFinishListener ofl = new OnFinishListener(){
  @Override public void onFinish( JSONObject o ){
    doSomethingOnJson( o );
  }
}
JSONObject response = VolleyHelper.getInstance(this).get(url, ofl );

JSONObject response = VolleyHelper.getInstance(this).post(url, params, ofl );
```

Comment: do you mean `VolleyHelper.getInstance(this).get(url, ofl );` without `JSONObject response =` because it should return nothing?

Comment: yes, no `get`, because it is blocking and block the main-thread is the last thing you want to do